# Data between forms & inaccesible duo to its protection level

Tags: c#

Im trying to make a quite simple game but its having an error.

I have three forms. bounce, ball and Option
in the option form I have 3 radiobuttons . Easy, medium and hard.

But when im trying to get my If to work in bounce. I get an error under easyradio
that says 'bounce.options.easyradio' is inaccessible due its protection level

```
 options tf = new options();
    public void optionbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tf.ShowDialog(this);
        if (
            tf.easyradio.Checked)
        {
            Random randwind = new Random();
            Ball.w = -5 + randwind.Next(5);
        }
```

The code in my option form for button easy is looking like this

```
  public void easy_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I really don't know how to solve this problem -

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `easyradio` modifier to `public`. You can do this from Form designer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the optionBtn_Click is in the options class.

In that case ditch the "tf." in front of everything, you're already in the class scope, and you're trying to use an instance of a class from it's definition.